# Is there a way to get attributes of children in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need get attribute from each children of my component (children are custom elements).

```js
class Pie extends React.Component {
    state = {
        items: React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <svg>

            </svg>
        </div>
    }
}

class PieItemElement extends HTMLBRElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.style.display = "none";
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ["value", "color", "name"];
    }
}

customElements.define("pie-item", PieItemElement);
// example of Pie element
const jsx = <Pie>
    <pie-item color="#FF0" value="256" name="USA" />
    <pie-item color="#00F" value="100" name="Canada" />
    <pie-item color="#F00" value="5000" name="Russia" />
</Pie>;
```

// Why do I need it
I am preparing library ([JSPie](https://jspie.github.io/)) and I have pure JS code already. I must create usual instance new Pie(...). And I want to create this syntax, but please help me, I don't know how to get attributes
The result:

[image: A pie chart]

Thank you for your time

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? What are you using the attributes for in the parent? Is there a reason you need to use custom elements instead of React components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to read `observedAttributes` of `PieItemElement` in your `Pie` component? If that's the case i believe [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) would allow you to hack some solution, keep in mind that this is considered to be a bad practice tough.